# how to save config file with date&time in a folder

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to automatically back-up the start-up config for my routers, but it will overwrite the previous one. How can I save naming date&time to the back-up file to avoid overwriting.
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Command [clock](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm) will help you with time-related stuff. As everything is a string, you can just insert the formatted date to the filename to be opened. `w+` means opening file for writing and creating it if it didn't exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set f [open "[clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"].txt" w+]
puts $f "foo"
close $f
```

Comment: To move a file, you want [`file rename`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M30)